# Print from iPad within browser using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf, ipad, printing

We recently started using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer to display pdfs embedded in our site.  The only button we have enabled is the print button.  When the user clicks print on an ipad the print preview shows correctly but when they select a printer the preview switches to a snapshot of the webpage. We can't give them the ability to download the pdf because it contains sensitive data.

Is this a limitation of the ipad?  Chrome?  The plugin we are using?